How can life without humans continue its addiction to self-destruction?
On an Earth where somewhen humans have disappeared, due to some global pandemic or war or cataclysmic event, how can lifeforms that survived - few animals, insects, plants, bacteria - which have since acquired self-awareness as a whole meaningless entity, and one de-facto addiction to self-destruction, continue on their deadly path, when paradoxically all the elements are once again coming together for a resurgence of life?
(humans are not that important in that regard, and some survivors would take part in that self-annihilating effort) What reason, if any, could push Life to refute and refuse billions of years of fighting for living, and instead chose the death path?
edit: self-awareness of all remaining lifeforms that their doomed condition on that pale wet rock, in a distant future when maybe DNA itself got coded towards extinction rather than survival(?) remaining life being aware that universe is vast, and life probably does its thing elsewere successfully; like that remaining sample of life decided to stop reproducing here, denying the initial code, becoming fatalist as a whole (?) sorry for bad phrasing hope this clears up a bit.

@Trioxidane's answer is pretty much the only answer. All life on Earth evolved in a competitive environment. Humanity isn't an aberration (as much as some might want to think so), it's merely what you get when you add sapience to the effort to evolve. Thus, everything on Earth that survived the cataclysm are naturally competitive and will be driven to even greater extremes in competition for the ostensibly limited post-cataclycm resources. In other words, there was never a paradox. What makes you think there is a paradox?

@JBH agreed, still your comment is about how life could survive, as it always does, question is rather about how would non-human, newly-sapient life as a whole, manage its regression, in a (maybe?) non-competitve self aware auto-destructive way.

I don't get the question. There seem to be some implicit assumptions - none of which are explained. perhaps you can edit to tell us: 1) How life "acquired self-awaereness as a whole meaningless entity"? 2) How that "self-awaereness" works in terms of their being "a whole meaningless entity" (I honestly have no idea what that means) 3) What an addiction to self destruction means in your world.

Thanks for the edit to clear up the typo, but that doesn't make the question substantially clearer to me.

@Escapeddentalpatient. tried to add context, not sure if this makes any more sense. not sure if life itself becoming "ill" makes sense at all.

Our problem is this: we have (theoretically) one data point when it comes to sapient terrestrial life: humans. We could stretch that to chimps and porpoises, but when it comes to how creatures think in an intelligent world, we have just one. Asking us how your alien species thinks (and that's what it is...) is brainstorming and opinion-based. The best we can do is Triox's answer. They evolved on the same planet under the same conditions of competition. They're likely to act like us. Or not. It's the "or not" that's the problem. It's just a guess. Pick your solution and run with it.

One more thing: it helps if we're dealing with specific definitions when it comes to sapient vs. sentient. A sentient creature is self-aware, meaning it can comprehend when things happen to it and react, (make a choice), to that stimuli. Plants (e.g.) aren't sentient. Most animals (e.g.) are. A sapient creature is endowed with "the divine gift of reason," such a creature can develop language and actually change the world around it. That's why chimps, etc. are on the border. They're a problem-solving species... but they can't change the world around them without Hollywood's help. ...

... A sapient creature is, by definition, also sentient. So, are your creatures sapient, or just sentient?

@JBH not sure. Whats left is a collection of various sentient creatures together forming maybe one single alien creature endowed with the agnostic trait of reason

Great. Now we know what you want, but you're tying to solve the design of your creature(s) in one question. I don't suggest this often, but I recommend you abandon this question and start analyzing your critters from the [tag:creature-design] perspective, then break the problem down into (much) smaller chunks. This has the potential to be very cool, but creating an entire alien personality, notably a hive personality, is more than we can do in a single question.

@JBH agreed, thanks for your advices!

Competition
Agression, and self destruction further down that vein, are necessary for life. There is competition everywhere. From the most simole life form to the highest.
Imagine a piece of sugar, an amazing fuel for food. Bacteria A and B alcome upon it, and start multiplying. At first everything is good, until they expand enough to meet each other. There is enough food, theoretically, but bacteria close to each other won't notice. Both try to get what they require, which is an impossibility. Even if they don't mean to, they are competing against each other. If one is more agressive it can get enough food, while the other wilters. Pushing, weakening or killing the other will give them access to the scarce resource. A and B will adopt strategies to still reproduce despite the other. From helping each other to releasing chemicals to kill.
This competition is obviously also possible within a colony. A bacteria if A can vie with another from A. They can battle it out in the same way, the ones with winning strategies having a better chance of survival.
This competition works on every level of complexity of life. Whether a humble amoeba or a newly minted intelligent life form. Each eventually has competition. They do not want to get eaten, or need to have access to clean water. The agression can be defending yourself with a stick or walking away. All are a form of aggression to the other species.
This competition is easily fostered, even with 'non-aggressive' creatures. Access to certain food, technology, social groups or even just access to the other sex. All can be seeds of agression. In humans it is no different. You see agression over fear of running out of food, or affordable gas, or simply because Chad slept with Barbie, causing Ken to use a gun, in his mind solving his reproductive blockage. This agression can be found in the micro and the macro, and is easily induced into all creatures.
Competition is a part of life. Any new life will have billions of years of evolution pushing to keep their environment stable and allow them to reproduce. So if a new lifeform arises, they need to overcome this hard wired competition that can too easily lead to self destruction.

competition is survival instinct par excellence, starving to death if sugar cube runs out is still fighting for life. question is rather what are fighting for death strategies, in a blooming world fully replenished of sugar cubes

@user721108 exactly true. We currently live in a world with for humans replenishing sugar cubes. Yet we fear of running out regardless. We bomb houtni rebels for fear some prices will go up. We hold countries in economic choke holds for cheap labour and products. Whether a specific kind of sugar cube is in danger of being removed or getting expensive, we compete. Collaboration not to die is how we get to self destruction. If you do not allow us oil, we will make sure no one has. Our collective will nuke the planet if our standards are impacted.

Homeostatic imbalance.
A living organism maintains a controlled internal environment.  It does not need to be constant, but there is some target set-point for the level of any chemical, and for any physical condition such as temperature or heart rate.  When an organism is alive, all these quantities move toward some predictable value, but when it is dead, they drift at random.  Diagnostic compounds like putrescine are produced, which are not themselves anything very bad, but signify chemical chaos internally.  Breath stops, the body goes cold, the eyes fade as oxygen no longer reaches the hemoglobin behind them.
Earth was an example of a living planet.  It had a body temperature you could measure down to the degree.  Its bodily fluids had a healthy working pH.  Its biochemistry was full of a few complex chemicals like chlorophyll, and mostly devoid of many others such as nitrogen oxides, DDT, and perfluoroalkyl compounds.
Humanity destroyed this biochemistry, and the collapse of this biochemistry destroyed humanity.  But like a patient who kills a virus by breathing his last breath, the Earth did not recover when humanity was gone.  Life persisted, but with every organism striving for its own benefit in an unrecognizable ecosystem that could not recover its natural balance.  For example, decomposers breeding in the oceans drained them of oxygen and killed the fish, which added to the decomposition - 'dead zones' grew until the entire ocean was as anoxic as the bottom of the Black Sea, where Byzantine ships lie untouched by living metabolism.  But these oceans are a dead Black Sea, contaminated with chemicals that kill most living things, which are still being churned out by new organisms such as photosynthetic yeast designed to produce industrial chemical products.  Mammals burrowed into trash dumps and abandoned radioactive stores of grain, accumulating more and more mutations each year, far beyond the ability of natural selection to purge within the corresponding interval of time, until the burden of genetic disease became too high for them to breed at all.  There are winners in this, just as there are bacteria that breed in a corpse - but like those bacteria, the winners here cannot persist long.  Eventually the planet, like the corpse of a man, will putrefy and breathe its last.  Just as releasing some bacteria on Mars would not guarantee life is still there twenty years later, retaining a few life forms on Earth does not guarantee it will recover or survive.

Law of unintended consequences and a critical mass
Imagine a 3 organism system: Plants, Deer and Wolves.
Deer eat the plants, but as they move, they spread the plant seeds in their poop, ensuring that the plants flourish. The wolves eat the Deer and the Wolves fight and die - when they die, their bodies rot and are reclaimed by nature - fertilizing the soil.
If the Wolves grow, they kill too many Deer, the Grass grows more, the Wolves starve for a bit, then the Deer flourish, eating the Grass spreading it wide etc. Ad infinitum - in short, Nature generally gets to an approximate equilibrium.
Now - let us tweak this system for a bit:
Assume the Wolves when they die, release a toxic chemical that is harmful to plants. This means that the Wolves are reducing the food source for their food source.
But - even then, Nature would find a way to achieve a balance - so we need a critical mass event:
One where there is enough damage done in a short period of time that it causes a chain reaction for which there is no recovery.
A natural disaster that causes a large amount of wolves to die in a single event would be a good option (in this scenario) - this poisons a large enough area to wipe out the grass, the Deer flourish for a bit, eating all the grass, but the ground is tainted and when they poo out the seeds, new grass does not grow - then the deer starve and their population shrinks, then the wolves starve and the rest of them die - which makes the ground impossible for grass to grow - leading to the last few Deer to starve.
Now - quick caveat - this is massively over-simplified and in the real world, there are so many factors that would be at play - but you get the Idea - something has a detrimental effect - it has to then be triggered at a scale that causes a cascading failure.

A World without Pollinators
Imagine a world in which humans produce so much insecticide that all pollinators die off.  Annuals and perennials all start to die off as their reproductive method is gone.  This leads to a collapse in the food web where the only plants left will be long lived trees dating back hundreds if not thousands of years to the time of humanity.  The problem is that anywhere that herbivores are too numerous, they kill the trees and there are no new trees to replace them; so, the most successful herbivores would be the ones who are self destructive.  The have no fear of trying new and possibly poisonous foods, they pick fights with bigger strong animals risking certain death to protect their territories, etc. They may even be quick to murder and cannibalism.
All these features together will mean that they force low population densities which will allow the trees enough time to grow new foliage without being over grazed.  In contrast, other herbivores who historically go through cycles of over population, famine, and recovery will not be able to recover because overpopulation will become a problem from which there is no coming back.
So even if their self-destructive life cycle makes them barely successful as a species, in this environment, being barely successful is way more sustainable than being exceptionally successful.
